# Python Request with Cert

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I am trying to embed the cert in the file and not call it via the file, because where I need to drop the script, calling files might not work.

Here is the current code:

```
cert = (r"example.crt",r"example.key")
r = requests.post("https://example.com",headers=pHeaders,json=data,cert=cert,verify=False)
```

This is working, however I am looking for something like the code below:

```
cert = """--- cert file in string format ---"""
key = """--- key file in string format ---"""
r = requests.post("https://example.com",headers=pHeaders,json=data,cert=cert,verify=False)
```

However the cert function needs a file. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

```py
import requests
import tempfile

cert = """--- cert file in string format ---"""
key = """--- key file in string format ---"""

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f_cert, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f_key:
    f_cert.write(cert.encode("utf-8"))
    f_cert.seek(0)

    f_key.write(key.encode("utf-8"))
    f_key.seek(0)

    r = requests.get(
        "https://example.com", cert=(f_cert.name, f_key.name)
    )
```

Comment: I get the following error when using this approach: ```path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _TemporaryFileWrapper```

Comment: @WianCrous Did you use `f_cert.name` and `f_key.name`? (Note the `.name`)

Comment: I did change it to f_cert.name and f_key.name, now I am getting the following error:
```requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))```

Answer (score 0):

## Never save keys/certs  to file from ENV or memory

it's proven to be [an unsafe practice](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-managing-service-account-keys#file-system).

## Do the following:

There is a hack to make new versions of `request` and `pyOpenSSL` able to handle serialized base64-coded certs/keys.
You may initially serialize a cert and a key into a string with the following command:

```
~$cat my_precious_private_key.key | base64
```

Here is the way how to make a `post` request:

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import FILETYPE_PEM, load_certificate, load_privatekey
import base64

BASE64_CERT_STRING = "<serialized cert>"
BASE64_KEY_STRING = "<serialized key>"

# Hack to use old pyopenssl with new urllib3
import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()

class Pkcs12Context(
          requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.OpenSSL.SSL.Context
      ): 
    def __init__(self, method):
        super().__init__(method)
        self.use_certificate(load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, base64.b64decode(BASE64_CERT_STRING)))
        self.use_privatekey(load_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, base64.b64decode(BASE64_KEY_STRING)))
 
# Save the original context, then replace the request context with your handmade one
original_context = requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.OpenSSL.SSL.Context
requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.OpenSSL.SSL.Context = Pkcs12Context

#  Nice! Make a call: 
response = requests.post(
    url, 
    headers={"Content-Type": "text/xml"}, #  or "Application/text"
    data=payload,
    timeout=60)

pass  # — process the response

# Do not forget to reset the original context!
requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.OpenSSL.SSL.Context = original_context
```

Also `FILETYPE_TEXT` [is available](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#:%7E:text=ValueError%20is%20raised.-,Serialization,-and%20deserialization) for keys.